# Simple Spring MVC Application - Error in configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My application has below 2 classes.

**DrawingApplication.java** -

```
package org.vamsi.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class DrawingApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Triangle triangle = new Triangle();

    BeanFactory factory= new XmlBeanFactory(new    
               FileSystemResource("spring.xml"));
    Triangle triangle = (Triangle)factory.getBean("triangle");
    triangle.draw();
    }
}
```

**Triangle.java** -

```
package org.vamsi.spring;

public class Triangle {

public void draw()
    {
        System.out.println("Triangle");
    }
}
```

My `spring.xml` File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"  
http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
     <bean id="triangle" class="org.vamsi.spring.Triangle"/>
</beans>
```

It shows my 2nd line in spring.xml is error. I downloaded spring framework  4.1.6 release and directly added to build path. I downloaded commoms-logging 1.0.4.jar and added 'commons.logging 1.2' to build path.
My java Version is 1.7 and i am using eclipse.

Comment: specify the spring version and post your classpath / pom.xml

Comment: Since it looks like you're starting with Spring: Use Spring Boot and skip all of the hand configuration. Initializr will generate a complete ready-to-launch skeleton.

Answer (score 1):

Exception is because you have not added `commons-logging` jar in your `classpath`. I think you have added zip file. Try to unzip and add the jar file as it will show like `commons-logging-1.2`.

If you are added the jar in lib folder try to add it to **build path**. To run the project without exception we have to add all the required jars to the build path.

Comment: I added all the jar files to my project by creating a new User library and added in the build path. I have unzipped and added commons-logging-1.2. It says my 2nd line in spring.xml is a mistake.

Comment: @Vamsi547, Are you sure about `FileSystemResource` to load `xml` file, instead try with `ClassPathResource`. I tried and it working perfectly